# hint vs point in the exam's sentence

Tags: vocabulary

Many of the pictures of herbs and plants **hint**/**point** that it may have been some kind of textbook for an alchemist.

Is it possible to prove to the national exam commission that point is correct answer? Can it be right here or absolutely no? 
Thanks and sorry for strange question. That was in my exam. I made a mistake here. But I thought it's correct answer too.

Answer (score 1):

*Point* has transitive meanings, such as "punctuate" and "emphasize", but in the gestural sense it is intransitive. If you want to mention the object of the action you must use a preposition phrase with *to*, *toward*, *at* or something similar.

> Many of the pictures point **to** the fact that &c.

Note also that none of these will take a 'content' clause (one with a finite verb, optionally introduced by *that*) as its object; you must 'nominalize' the object by casting the verb as a gerund (*point to its **having been***) or by employing an actual noun phrase, as I have done above.

Consequently, *point* cannot be a correct answer. *Hint*, however, is transitive: it does take an object. And that object may be cast as a content clause.